# CCAvenue integration in Nodejs and React js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, payment-gateway, web-frontend, ccavenue

I am trying to integrate ccAvenue payment gateway.
I've worked on the Razorpay payment gateway before. as Razorpay provides an SDK for front-end to open the payment gateway window, is there any way to do same for ccAvenue ?

I've Reactjs in front-end and Nodejs in back-end.